# Making sense of Ubuntu Server Status Info

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, monit

I'm trying to create a simple shell script to monitor my server. I plan to set up a CRON job to run it every five or 10 minutes.

Here's how it will work:

1. Run a number of linux commands e.g. iostat, mpstat, top, etc. and output the results to a text file
2. Send the text file via CURL to a URL that will receive the text file and process the data, and then post important metrics to a database

I plan to use this data to determine when I need to have my server upgraded.

However, I don't have much experience with server monitoring so I don't know what kind of thresholds I should be looking out for. For example, when I run something like `mpstat -P ALL`, what kind of figures should bother me? Or `iostat`?

I just want to be able to have some kind of point of reference to know when my servers are in a good state i.e. reasonable load, or in a bad state i.e. overloaded, and require upgrade or load-balancing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It kinda seems like you are asking for help to reinvent the wheel here.  There are loads of monitoring systems.  Search around the site.

Comment: @Zoredache: I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, I just need some perspective. I just want to be able to make sense of data provided by the simple tools already available on Ubuntu linux like top, iostat, mpstat etc. Plus, I'm not looking for a ready-made graphical tool because I don't need all that visibility, I'm just looking at thresholds i.e. good or bad.

Comment: I agree with Zoredache, you are reinventing the wheel. With a combination of munin and nagios you can collect, visualise, and alert on any number of performance and health metrics.

Comment: @GraemeDonaldson: I don't dispute that there are tools out there for server monitoring. However, as I said in my question, I don't have a point of reference to know what the data is saying i.e. is 80% of memory usage bad or ok, Is 20% swap usage bad or ok, etc.?! That's my issue, I'm trying to find some good information and perspectives on thresholds so that I know just when to setup alerts. Are  there any specific metrics you work with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that the [free Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) would be a more appropriate tool for testing the thresholds you're looking for and giving a simple [at-a-glance view](http://mmonit.com/monit/screenshots/images/screenshots/1.png) of your system's health.

Out of the box, you can setup some basic checks. The syntax is very human-readable, so a barebones setup that checks system load, memory usage, swap utilization, CPU usage and disk space for various mountpoints, and can send an email would look like this:

```
if loadavg (1min) > 6 then alert
if loadavg (5min) > 5 then alert
if memory usage > 90% then alert
if swap usage > 20% then alert
if cpu usage (user) > 90% then alert
if cpu usage (system) > 75% then alert
if cpu usage (wait) > 75% then alert

check device root with path /
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

check device var with path /var
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

check device usr with path /usr
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert

check device tmp with path /tmp
    if SPACE usage > 80% then alert
```

In addition, I know you're saying that you don't require any graphical tools, but it may make sense to have something that can [track trends](http://munin.ping.uio.no/ping.uio.no/rossum.ping.uio.no-df.html). [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) is a good tool for this. There are plenty of others, but it's worth considering.

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, I have no idea what thresholds are safe and unsafe i.e. should it be 80% of memory usage or 90%?! That's my main problem, I don't really know what thresholds to work with.

Comment: What I posted is a good start. Adjust accordingly if the thresholds are triggered too often. Thresholds are unique to environments and applications. There are some situations where it's perfectly healthy for a server to run at a load of 10... There are others where that's a sign of a major resource problem. This is going to be a very individual thing.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I know it's an individual thing. I'm just looking for some basic info. For example, what you had above with `if swap usage > 20% then alert` how did you arrive at that? I don't know how to read the data. All tolled, it looks like Monit can do what I need. I'm sure I can put together a shell script to send the data for each server using CURL. I just need to figure out how to read meaning into all the data provided as I'm not a very seasoned system administrator.

Answer (score 1):

Obi Hill: Well, you ARE reinventing the wheel. Gathering all that data, parsing it and analysing it is a solved problem you should not rewrite Yet Another Time.

SNMP is one very handy way of gathering system information for further processing (for example, graphing trends with `MRTG` or passing the data to `Nagios` or similar monitoring program).

Also programs like `Cacti` or `Munin` can do all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

How many servers do you have?

Perhaps you should take a look at Puppet, RunDesk or ControlTier.